# In Selenium IDE how do I assert that there is a button on a webpage containing a specific string?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

For example: if I want to assert that there is a button or link containing the string "Sig" (so it should return true if a button or link says "Sign up"), how do I do that? I'm assuming my command should be assertText but what do I put for target and/or value?

Answer (score 0):

Target is xpath for your element, i.e button or link. For ex;      `//button[@clasd='foo']`  
Value is your search string:Sign up

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows you how you can search for exact test (first check) and for partial match (2nd check)

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://www.google.com/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//input[@value=&quot;Google Search&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//input[contains(@value,&quot;Google S&quot;)]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

But here is another example looking at the text in a link:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>//div[@id='footcnt']//span[2]/a[1]</td>
    <td>Adv*</td>
</tr>
```

Which should verify the link "advertising" on the google home page.